Connecting three way switch to Lutron dimmer
My old light switch has connected black, red, and white wires. My new Lutron unit has a black, red, and a red/white wire. I’m seeking guidance on which wires to connect together for this three way to work.



old receptacle ???? From everything else, it sounds like your old switch. Please clarify. Also, do you know whether this switch has power coming in or if the power comes in to the other switch?

Yeah sorry I meant switch. I’m replacing the old switch with the new Lutron one. I’m not really sure where power goes to where unfortunately.

What color is the screw that the white wire is next to? Do you have a non-contact voltage tester like this? If so, see which wire(s) show voltage when the switches are off - that should help figure out which switch is "line" and which is "load", which often matters a lot for connecting smart, dimmer, etc. switches.

Using a pen tester I’ve concluded the following: when switch is switched to ON the black and the white wires are hot. When switch is switched to OFF the white wire only is hot. Both ON and OFF the red wire is never hot.

Last piece to figure this out (hopefully) - if you flip the other switch to the opposite position (three-way switches aren't "ON"/"OFF", they are just "UP"/"DOWN") then what wires show hot (still in this original switch) when this switch is switched Up/Down?

If this is a smart switch, using it in a three-way configuration may require reassigning traveler wires, or replacing a specific switch out of the pair... If it's possible at all. What do the installation instructions for this switch say about 3-way use? What's the specific model number of the new switch?

When I zoom the photo of the old switch I can see the black terminal is labeled "COMMON".
Based on the comments, it sounds like the existing black wire is connected to the light or "load".
You can use the manufacturer's instructions to finish the work with that info.
If you need more help then please post the part number of the new switch.
Also beware the old switch is not properly grounded.  You will need to correct this problem.
